# How to send JLabel items using nested arraylist to Apache POI

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I have a nested arraylist consisting of Productname and price within a while loop that Im trying to send to Apache POI Java program in eclipse to create a MS word invoice from my cart items. Problem is, only two items are being written into the word document and it seems the remaining function calls are not taking place to add further products and price. How do I fix this issue? Is there a way to reduce function calls? Im a beginner and this is a really important piece of code for my project. Please help

Here is my code:-

```
          Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = bl.iterator();

          while(itr.hasNext())
          {
            ArrayList<String> al = itr.next();

            try {
                n=z.writeData(al.get(0), al.get(1));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                                try {
            z.closeFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
                               Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
          try {
            rt.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\winword.exe C:\\Users\\kaustav\\Desktop\\"+n+".docx");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          }
```

my code to generate the product price and name-

```
  public int writeData(String name, String price) throws IOException
 {
     paragraph=document.createParagraph();
     paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setFontSize(20);
     run.setTextPosition(40);
     run.setText(name+"   "+price);


     document.write(out);

     return n;
 }
```

the output should be that under Product name more than 2 items should be named and under Product Price their respective prices in my MS Word document but I only get upto 2 products and their prices. The remaining are not written into my MS Word document. Please help !!

Comment: at this line `document.write(out);`. what is `out`?

Comment: Its the output file stream:- FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File("the path"));  the code was too long to be included here

Comment: [POIXMLDocument.write](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-): "Once this has been called, no further operations, updates or reads should be performed on the document.". So do not write out the document after each new paragraph. Add all the paragraphs first and then write the document once after that.